# How Can I Secure HTML Files that are Created Dynamically in My ASP.NET 4 Web App?

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, authentication

I am running an ASP.NET 4 application on a Windows 8 R2 server with IIS 7. The application dynamically creates HTML files in a sub-directory "Reports" within the app's root directory. I am attempting to secure these files using the already existing Forms Authentication by making the following changes to the web.config file:

Added these four lines to the `<compilation>` section:

```
  <buildProviders><br />
    <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" /> <br />
    <add extension=".htm" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" /> <br />
  </buildProviders> <br />
```

Added these four lines to the `<system.web>` section:

```
<httpHandlers><br />
  <add verb="*" path="*.htm" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" /><br />
  <add verb="*" path="*.html" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" /><br />
</httpHandlers><br />
```

Tried both of the following

```
"<handlers>" in the "<system.webServer>" section:<br />
<handlers><br />
      <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG"   type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" /><br />
      <add name="HTM" path="*.htm" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" /><br />
</handlers><br />
```

and

```
<handlers><br />
      <add name="HtmlHandler-Integrated" path="*.html" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" /><br />
      <add name="HtmHandler-Integrated" path="*.htm" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" /><br />
</handlers><br /><br />
```

Finally, I added a `<location>` tag to specify the "role-based" security for the folder:

```
  <br />
  <location path="Reports"><br />
    <system.web><br />
      <authorization><br />
        <allow roles="Administrator, Base User" /><br />
        <deny users="*" /><br />
      </authorization><br />
    </system.web><br />
  </location><br /><br />
```

These settings work fine for non-authenticated users, but produce the error "The file '....htm' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested." for the HTML files that are dynamically created from the application.

What other changes are necessary to protect these "html" files from non-authenticated users?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I'm assuming you can't use a database for some reason. You may instead want to use a Handler to do the authentication/authorization, instead of adding all those entries. Make the HTML not available directly, but instead via a handler (perhaps an ASHX), and have the handler do the checking.

Comment: The application currently opens the HTML files in a POPUP window using a Javascript "window.Open" call. I prefer to keep the current architecture and functionality if possible. I could write the HTML to another folder that is not in the APP folder structure and then open and Write the contents of file to another ASPX page. Is that what you mean by "Make the HTML available via a handler..."?

Comment: I solved my own problem by changing the functionality to write the HTML files to a directory not contained in the applications web site. I then created a new ASP.NET page to open the HTML file, read and store its contents into a Literal control on the page. I had read somewhere that the "Mode" tag for the Literal control had to be set to "PassThrough". My HTML files are being displayed properly without that tag being set. I did have to eliminate the use of the Master Page in the new ASP.NET page. I added the following to the top of the page:

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" .... %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns:MXSXL="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:DT="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" xmlns:User="http://localhost" xmlns:O="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:W="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/tr/rec-html40)">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
<meta name="ProgId" content="Word.Document"/>